# superclass with private static field and subclass calls a method that changes the field, Why doesn't the field change?

Tags: java, inheritance, field, member-hiding

```
public class B {

    private static  boolean goo=true;

    protected static boolean foo() {
        goo=!goo;
        return goo;
    }

    public String bar="Base:"+foo();

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        B base=new A();
        System.out.println("Base:"+goo);//***prints Base:true***
    }
}

public class A extends B{
    public String bar="Sub:"+foo();
}
```

Why does the program print `true` instead of `false`, I don't understand why `goo` didn't change after `foo()` was called. `goo` isn't hidden because it is a private field. the static field before creating an object is `true`, then when `foo` occurs isn't it supposed to change `goo` in Heap?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: In your case: why using a boolean that **toggles** between true and false. Change it to int, and simply keep increasing the counter, and printing the counter. Otherwise, really include **all** output, and clearly describe where the actual output does not match your expectation.

Comment: why would you need two `public String bar`? one switches the value to `false` and the other then back to `true`

Comment: Why is 'public String bar="Base:"+foo(); 'called?

Comment: because that's the way Java works. It needs to call `foo()` to initialize it. And in your case it is called twice

Comment: If I change 'B base=new A();' to 'A base=new A();' it still prints the same thing, so it means that foo is still called twice? And it has nothing to with that the static type was B but with the fact that A inherits from B? Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is well explained in[Panz0r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396907/4391450) but what you don't see is that you have two variable call `bar`, one in `A` one in `B`.

If you add a method to print the instance members in both class (and `A` will also print is super class):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B base = new A();
        System.out.println(base);
    }
}

class B {

    private static boolean goo = true;

    protected static boolean foo() {
        goo = !goo;
        return goo;
    }

    public String bar = "Base:" + foo();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return bar; //print the variable B.bar
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public String bar = "Sub:" + foo();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //print the instance B and the variable A.bar
        return super.toString() + "\n" + bar;
    }
}
```

You will see that both `bar` exist in an instance `A`

> Base:false
>   Sub:true

You could access `B.bar` variable using `super.bar` if the accessibility allowed it but it is private in your case.

A solution would be to use a constuctor `B` that will accept a value and concatenate the result of `foo`.

```
public String bar;

public B(){
    this("Base: ");
}

protected B(String source){ //protected to prevent anybody to use it directly
    bar = source + foo();
}
```

And in `A`

```
public A(){
    super("Sub: ");
}
```

Only the creation of `B` will call `foo` so you get the result :

> Sub: false

Let's check with this :

```
System.out.println(new A().bar);
System.out.println(new B().bar);
System.out.println(new A().bar);
```

> Sub: false
>   Base: true
>   Sub: false

Answer (score 3):

Because you change the value twice?

```
true -> public String bar="Base:"+foo(); -> false
false -> public String bar="Sub:"+foo(); -> true
```

Comment: Why is 'public String bar="Base:"+foo();' called?

Comment: Because `String bar` is an instance member, it will be created during the instantiation of an instance `A`. (`new A()`)

Comment: Yes, but it will create 'public String bar="Sub:"+foo();' why also  'public String bar="Base:"+foo();' ?

Comment: Both exist in different scope.

Comment: @Programmingfreak because `B` is also initialized when you're calling `new A()` and thus also its instance members are initialized